# How do I pass a variable from one action to another in a Rails controller?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

There is a situation where I need to call my `update` action from my `create` action:

```
def create
  @product = Product.find_or_initialize_by_sku(params[:sku])
  if @product.new_record?
    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @product, status: :created, location: @product }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  else
   update ##*** I am calling the update action at this point ***##
  end
end

def update
  @product = Product.find_or_initialize_by_sku(params[:sku])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @product.update_attributes(params[:product])
      format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    else
      format.html { render action: "edit" }
      format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

But I end up making two identical queries to my database because I am not sure of the most effective way to pass a variable (in this case, the instance variable `@product`) from one action to another.

I am trying to get a grasp on the 'rails' way to do this.  What should I do here (as I know I should not be making two identical database queries)?

Would I store it in the session as if I was performing a redirect (*Am I* performing a redirect when I call an action from within another action like this?)?

```
session[:product] = @product # in my create action
# then
@product = session[:product] # in my update action
```

Does caching make this all a moot point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using [memoization](http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/59-use-memoization):

```
@product ||= Product.find_or_initialize_by_sku(params[:sku])
```

The `||=` operator will check if `@product` is nil, and if it is, Ruby will execute the finder. Otherwise, Ruby will use the current value. Therefore, when you call `update` from `create`, the `update` method will use the `@product` that you found or initialized in `create`.

Regarding your second question, you're not performing a redirect when you call one controller action from another. Try not to over-think it - a controller is just another Ruby class with its own instance variables (e.g. `@product`) and methods. To perform a redirect, you would have to call [`redirect_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html#method-i-redirect_to), which would result in a second web request to your controller.

Comment: Well that's just wonderfully easy to implement (I'm learning Rails, coming from .NET).

Comment: Great to hear! Welcome to the party!